# App crashes while web scraping in WP 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, web-scraping

I am developing a WP 8 app for web scraping. For some reasons I don't know why, my app crashes in WP.

Here is my sample code:

```
private void Load(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://" + "www.google.com"); 
            req.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ResponseCallback), req);
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
    }

    private async void ResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asyncres)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest wreq = (HttpWebRequest)asyncres.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse wres = (HttpWebResponse)wreq.EndGetResponse(asyncres);

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wres.GetResponseStream());

            string result = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();

            //HTML View
            HTML.Text = result;

            //Readable
            string read;
            read = Regex.Replace(result, "<script.*?</script>", "", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            read = Regex.Replace(read, "<style.*?</style>", "", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            read = Regex.Replace(read, "</?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>", "");
            read = Regex.Replace(read, "<!--(.|\\s)*?-->", "");
            read = Regex.Replace(read, "<!(.|\\s)*?>", "");
            read = Regex.Replace(read, "[\t\r\n]", " ");

            readable.Text = read;
            }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
   }
```

However I am trying to get Emails, URLs and Scripts also at the same time with HTML and Readable text (so if that might be a problem ?)

Also I am not able to run Internet in my Windows Phone 8 Emulator (tried many things still doesn't work !) so I need to check this on physical device, and on that the application is crashing.

I have selected Networking Capability. (Please let me know if any other capability is required)

Please help me out, what am I missing here ?

Thanks,

Regards,

Rumman

Comment: Oh god, parsing HTML with RegExp again :(

Comment: don't worry it will work for my project ! :p
But here the problem is application is crashing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably because you are interacting with UI elements on a non-UI thread (the response callback).

Try to put the code interacting with UI elements in a `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` method, like so:

```
private async void ResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asyncres)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest wreq = (HttpWebRequest)asyncres.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse wres = (HttpWebResponse)wreq.EndGetResponse(asyncres);

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wres.GetResponseStream());

        string result = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();

        //HTML View
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            HTML.Text = result;
        });


        //Readable
        string read;
        read = Regex.Replace(result, "<script.*?</script>", "", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        read = Regex.Replace(read, "<style.*?</style>", "", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        read = Regex.Replace(read, "</?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>", "");
        read = Regex.Replace(read, "<!--(.|\\s)*?-->", "");
        read = Regex.Replace(read, "<!(.|\\s)*?>", "");
        read = Regex.Replace(read, "[\t\r\n]", " ");

        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            readable.Text = read;
        });

        }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer of @Olivier should work for you. Regarding Internet on Emulator, open `Network and Sharing Center` and check if there is a connection named `Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch` or something related to this. If not, go to `Change Adapter Settings` from left panel.  Again look for something related to `Emulator` there. Right click and Enable it if it is disabled.

This is the only reason i can think of.